# Javascript array - fill missing elements with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's assume I have two arrays with same length:

```
var a=[5,2,8,12,15,72,3,9];
var b=[,3,,5,19,,71,];
```

in Javascript, how can I merge these two arrays so that in every index the new array contains the corresponding `b` element, if is is not empty, the corresponding element of `a`.

The new array `c` should be:

```
c = [5,3,8,5,19,72,71,9]
```

Note: the order of the elements must not be changed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO? What have you tried so far? What's not working? Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update accordingly. Two things to look at would be the concept of `zip` and `map`.

Comment: loop over one array, if missing, use value from other array....

Answer (score -1):

So assuming that `A` will always have an element while it is not always true that `B` will have one. Then the below code should word.

Essentially just loop through `B` check if there is an input, if there is push it to the new array if not grab the value in `A`

This runs in linear time.

```js
var a=[5,2,8,12,15,72,3,9];
var b=[,3,,5,19,,71,];
function createNewArray(a, b){
let newArray = [];
for(let i=0;i<=b.length;i++){
    if(b[i]){
        newArray.push(b[i])
    } else {
        newArray.push(a[i])
    }
}
return newArray
}
console.log(createNewArray(a,b))
```